# Kinect SDK C++ linking error

Tags: c++, kinect

I know that this questions is answered, but for me is not working. In my project:

I included kinect inc, linked kinect lib\amd64 and additional kinect10.lib

For some reason I am getting a linking error:

```
1>Kinect.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__NuiCreateSensorByIndex@8 referenced in function "private: long __thiscall Kinect::connect(void)" (?connect@Kinect@@AAEJXZ)
1>Kinect.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__NuiGetSensorCount@4 referenced in function "private: long __thiscall Kinect::connect(void)" (?connect@Kinect@@AAEJXZ)
```

If I comment the two functions (NuiCreateSensorByIndex and NuiGetSensorCount) I am not getting a linking error, despite the fact that I am using other SDK's functions.

Comment: You know that the question has been answered before but you ask it again anyways? C'mon ... Besides that: If you have an answer put it in the answer form below. Don't answer it inside the question text.

Comment: I solved the problem later on. I was looking for a solution and evryone was saying to add kinect10.lib. The problem was that I already did that and I had the linking error. I can't understand why it can't link the 64bits and it is working with the 32 version.

Comment: I was adding lib\amd64, despite the fact that my machine is 64bits. When I changed to lib\x86 it worked.